# Achartengine's piechart does not refresh from repaint function

Tags: java, android, charts, pie-chart, achartengine

I'm building an application that makes piechart from database according to precise date interval. Unfortunately the achartengine's repaint function is not working when I'm stepping with the buttons.
When the Activity starts everything is fine the chart is okay but when i'm using the buttons then nothing happens.

I hope somebody can help me.

here is the code:

```
private GraphicalView chartView;
```

...

```
 tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("Grafikon")
            .setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
                    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(SumMenuActivity.this).inflate(
                            R.layout.summenu_tab3, null);

                    periodSeekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.summenutab3_periodslide);
                    final TextView periodName = (TextView) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.summenutab3_periodtw);

                    if (chartView == null) {
                        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
                        intValChanger(intVal, 0);
                        layout.addView(chartView);
                    } else {                           
                        chartView.repaint();
                    }

                    periodSeekBar
                            .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                        boolean fromUser) {
                                    if (progress == 0) {
                                        periodName.setText("Heti");
                                    } else if (progress == 1) {
                                        periodName.setText("Havi");
                                    } else if (progress == 2) {
                                        periodName.setText("Eves");
                                    }

                                    intVal = 0;
                                    intValChanger(intVal, progress);
                                }

                                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                }

                                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                }
                            });

                    final View minusButton = view.findViewById(R.id.summenutab3_frombutton);
                    final View plusButton = view.findViewById(R.id.summenutab3_tobutton);

                    minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            intVal--;
                            intValChanger(intVal, periodSeekBar.getProgress());
                            if (chartView != null) {
                                chartView.refreshDrawableState(); 
                                chartView.repaint();
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            intVal++;
                            intValChanger(intVal, periodSeekBar.getProgress());
                            if (chartView != null) {
                                chartView.refreshDrawableState(); 
                                chartView.repaint();
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    return view;
                }
```

...

```
 public void intValChanger(int intVal, int type) {

    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (type == 0) {

        start.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
        end.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
        int currentStartOfWeek = (start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7 - start
                .getFirstDayOfWeek()) % 7;
        int currentEndOfWeek = (end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7 - end.getFirstDayOfWeek()) % 7;
        start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -currentStartOfWeek + intVal * 7);
        end.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (-currentEndOfWeek + intVal * 7) + 6);

    } else if (type == 1) {

        start.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        start.set(Calendar.MONTH, start.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 * intVal);
        end.set(Calendar.DATE, start.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
        end.set(Calendar.MONTH, end.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 * intVal);

    } else if (type == 2) {

        start.set(Calendar.YEAR, start.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1 * intVal);
        start.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        start.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        end.set(Calendar.YEAR, end.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1 * intVal);
        end.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
        end.set(Calendar.DATE, 31);

    }

    if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0) {
        populateTimeList(start.getTime(), end.getTime());
    } else if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 1) {
        populateSumArrayList(start.getTime(), end.getTime());
    } else if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 2) {
        populateChart(start.getTime(), end.getTime());
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", start) +
                    "-tól " + android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", end)
                    + "-ig", 3).show();
}

public GraphicalView executeChart(Context context, ArrayList<String> name,
        ArrayList<Integer> value) {

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    CategorySeries categorySeries = new CategorySeries("Torta diagram");
    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        Random r = new Random();
        categorySeries.add(name.get(i), value.get(i));
        colors.add(Color.rgb(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256)));
    }

    DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(14);
    GraphicalView gview = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context,
            categorySeries, renderer);
    return gview;
}

protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(ArrayList<Integer> colors) {
    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int color : colors) {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(color);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    return renderer;
}

    public void populateChart(Date from, Date to) {
    ArrayList<String> tmpName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> tmpValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ArrayList<Category> tmpCategory = getCategories();
    ArrayList<Transaction> tmpTransaction = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tmpCategory.size(); i++) {
        tmpName.add(tmpCategory.get(i).getName());
        tmpTransaction = (ArrayList<Transaction>) getTransactionsByTimeIntvalAndId(from, to,
                tmpCategory.get(i).getId());
        int ammount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < tmpTransaction.size(); j++) {
            ammount += tmpTransaction.get(j).getAmmount();
        }
        tmpValue.add(ammount);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tmpName.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("DEBUG MESSAGE", tmpName.get(i) + ": " + tmpValue.get(i));

    }

    chartView = null;
    chartView = executeChart(SumMenuActivity.this, tmpName, tmpValue);

    Log.d("DEBUG MESSAGE", "megtörtént a repaint!" + chartView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Achart but this is a simple pie chart implementation. You can refer the demo and it might help.
In this demo after you update the values, you need to call invalidate() to redraw the pie chart.

https://github.com/blessenm/PieChartDemo